# How can I save data from an array into variables?

Tags: php

I want to save data from an Array into variables ...

```
$farm = array();

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Cat
            [name] => Tom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Dog
            [name] => Bob
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Bird
            [name] => Sam
        )
    [3] => ....
```

... so that I can use them to save them in a table or in a SQL database.

```
animal   name  
===============
Cat      Tom  
Dog      Bob  
Bird     Sam  
...
```

Comment: And what's stopping you from trying to fetch it?

Comment: So what's the issue over here don't you know how to fetch multidimensional array

Comment: Because I do not know what fetch mean :) but I will read about it, thanks for the advise

Comment: Like variables:
`$animal = $arr[0]['animal'];`
`$animalName = $arr[0]['name'];`

Comment: Thank you, the advice "fetch multidimensional array" was very helpful. I solved it like this: `foreach($farm as $row) {
      echo $row['animal'];
      echo $row['name'];`
               }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you got a pretty simple script for this:

```
<?php
$sql ='INSERT INTO table_name (animal,name) VALUES ';
$flag = true;

foreach($array as $item){

  if($flag){
      $sql.= '("'.$item['animal'].'","'.$item['name'].'")';
      $flag = false;
  }
  else
      $sql.= ',("'.$item['animal'].'","'.$item['name'].'")';

  }
$sql.=';';
//you do your database stuff here with the $sql query.
?>
```

As you can see you do not need to add them to a variable. You can go through on the array like this. I didn't care about making this better, but you get the idea I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your array and print all variables one by one

```
$arr = array( "0" => array(
        "animal" => "Cat",
        "name" => "Tom"
    ),

"1" => array(
        "animal" => "Dog",
        "name" => "Bob"
    ),

"2" => array(
        "animal" => "Bird",
        "name" => "Sam"
    )
);

echo "animal - Name <br>" ;

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
    echo $arr[$i]["animal"] . "- " . $arr[$i]["name"];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

its just a example in actual keep them in a table